# How to fetch kendoui datepicker select value in javascript

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to fetch selected datepicker value in javascript..my demo code is

```
$('body').find('.k-grid').delegate(".k-datepicker", "change", function(e) {

}
```

In above code i want to fetch date value,so please suggest me appropriate solution..

Comment: Information....Too short!

Comment: I use kendoui datepicker when i select date it will fetch into this code.I try by using this code

Comment: var date = $(".k-datepicker").kendoDatePicker().closest(".k-widget").attr("id");,, but it will not work . im not getting selected date value.

Comment: Why don't you use the built in kendo change function?

Comment: `var startDate = $("#datePickerID").val();`

Answer (score 1):

Use the Kendo API:

```
var datetimepicker = $("#datetimepicker").data("kendoDateTimePicker");
var dateValue = datetimepicker.value();
var endDateTime = $("#ScheduleEnd").data("kendoDateTimePicker").value();
```